# Consecutive form submits on same page

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I am trying to submit several consecutive forms, conditioned by previous form, then update database with new information.
If first question answered, then go to second question. If second question answered then go to third. If third question answered then update database.
My code is:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
    <?php
    // Database connection
    $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'admin', 'pass', 'TEST') 
    or die ('Cannot connect to db');

            // Var declared
            $Room = $_POST['Room'];
            $Name = $_POST['name'];
            $Tlf = $_POST['Tlf'];

        if(isset($_POST['Tlf']) && $_POST['Tlf'] != "") {
            // Last question answered, do your stuff
            echo "You have selected :" .$Room;
            echo "You have selected :" .$Name;
            echo "You have selected :" .$Tlf;            

        } elseif(isset($_POST['name']) && $_POST['name'] != "") {
            // Second question answered
            $Name = $_POST['name'];
            echo "<html>";
            echo "<body>";
            echo "<input type='text' name='Tlf' value=Telephone>";
            echo "<input type='submit' name='tlf_submit' value='Search_tlf'>";
            echo "</body>";
            echo "</html>";

        } elseif(isset($_POST['Room']) && $_POST['Room'] != "") {
            // First question answered
            echo "<html>";
            echo "<body>";
            echo "<input type='text' name='name' value=name>";
            echo "<input type='submit' name='name_submit' value='Search_name'>";
            echo "</body>";
            echo "</html>";
            } else {

    // Fetch info from database
    $result = $conn->query("select Room from TEST1 WHERE Room_status = 'OUT'");

    echo "<html>";
    echo "<body>";
    echo "<form action='' method='post'>";
    echo "<select name='Room'>";

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

                  unset($Room);
                  $Room = $row['Room']; 
                  echo '<option value="'.$Room.'">'.$Room.'</option>';

}

    echo "</select>";
    echo "<input type='submit' name='form_submit' value='Search'>";
    echo "</body>";
    echo "</html>";

//Update database with selected data
if(isset($_POST['form_submit'])){
$Room = $_POST['Room'];  // Storing Selected Value In Variable
$sql_insert_rom = "UPDATE TEST1
                                    SET 
                                    Room = $Room
                                    WHERE Room_status = 'TEST'";

                            if ($conn->query($sql_insert_rom) === TRUE) {
                    }
}
else {
echo "do nothing";
}

        }
    ?>

</form>
```

When running this i get:

```
You have selected :You have selected :You have selected :Telephone
```

When running the `// Fetch info from database`part separately, it works just fine.

I am obviously a novice here, so can you help me figure out why is my code not working as intended ?

In the meantime I am just going to write each part of the code as separate pages.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: This output comes from first condition. You only check one param and output rest and it seems that they are empty

Comment: So I guess I should try to store the variables as session variables ?
In the meantime, like I said, I just wrote all as separate code, and it's working, but I still want to find out how to make the original idea work.

Comment: It should work if you move first condition to the end of `ifelse` sequence.